# Troubles with installing openstack

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, openstack

I should do for my master thesisi some tutorials for administrators how to set, manage and use openstack.
On my workstation 9 I set ubuntu server x64 12.04 lts, then I try to do quick istall by devstack `http://devstack.org/`. I am usinh NAT.

So I typed terminal:

1. git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
2. cd devstack && ./stack.sh

After runing stack.sh dscript in shows me error:

```
Could not open requirements file: [Errno2] No such file or directory: '*-info/requires.txt'
Storing complete log in /home/robetr/.pip/pip.log
+sudo HTTP_PROXY=HTTPS_PROXY=python setup.py develop
paython: can't open file setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
++ failed
+local r=2
+set +o xtrace
```

After that I tried with:

1. sudo
2. make update
3. make upadete & apgrade  here where installing more then 250mb of new updates and so on
4. then I make 
   sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
5. then 
   sudo easy_install
6. sudo easy_install BeautifulSoup
7. sudo aptitude install python-beautifulsoup
8. then I actualy find setup.py in opt/stack/python-openstackclient/setup.py

Then some thing instaled, upgrade and so on. But one again ewhen I tried to run in devstack/stack.sh  script in broke down.

I waste 2 days to play with this and didn't come far. Have any ideas?

Regards, Robert

Comment: you probably better start with the openstack packages for 12.04 LTS, should be easier than install upstream source.

Comment: I am also having problems with installing devstack. Did you sorted out?